# How to host an intern webpage and mysql data base?

Tags: php, mysql, server

I am looking for a way to host a webpage and a mySQL data base but in internal network, like an intranet for example.

When I was working on the website and the database, I used MAMP to emule a server on my PC but this work only on one PC. I'm looking for a way to share this website on different PC but only on my internal network.

*Sorry for bad english. If there's something not understandable, please ask.
If it's a "repost question", please lead me to the answer I'm looking for. If you need more information, be pleased to ask them.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAMP and others should work. You might be visiting http://localhost:1234/index.php on your machine so on your network on other device, try http://yourmachinename:1234/index.php. As long as the ports are open, this should work.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is very sensitive I would go for an external webhotel like godaddy.com or similar in your country. And add password protection on the site.

If you want to host it you need a computer that is on 24/7 and install your setup there, but then you are required to handle hardware failures, updating the software and so on.

Comment: It's very sensitive data. But thanks dude.